# Is there any mvc architecture for express and angular?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express

I want to learn angular with express and MySQL, using MVC architecture.
I have a web app, https://github.com/NicolasMarino/Links-App but it only uses express and there is no MVC, I want a basic setup of how it works MVC in express, with MySQL and angular. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MVC = model/view/controller. Your angular app would be your view and express would be your controller. All you need to do is point your api calls from your angular app to your express server at whatever port you're running it on.
i.e. if you're running express on port 8080, you would typically just write a call like so in angular:

```
import HttpClient from '@angular/common/http';

this.http.get('localhost:8080/routename').subscribe( data => {
    // do whatever you want with your data here
    console.log(data);
});
```

you obviously need to create routing in your express app for your angular app to call.

I would recommend Traversy Media's MEAN app tutorial if you want to get a quick overview. It's a mongodb, express, angular, node webapp but you can substitute your mysql db for the mongodb.

Comment: So, i just create routing in angular and  the routing for the api in express right? Thank you!